# how to deploy express node app in AWS Lambda along with npm modules?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to deploy my node app in AWS lambda. The npm packages I am using are not pre-installed in lambda. So how can I deploy the whole node app in lambda? There is a option of uploading the files as a zip file. But how can I build the correct lambda file system?

Comment: Check this out https://bitbucket.org/blog/deploy-an-express-js-app-to-aws-lambda-using-the-serverless-framework

Answer (score 0):

You need to zip the file contents. basically

```
somezip.zip
   node_modules
   index.js
   anyotherffile.js
   package.json
```

Upload the zip and call the exposed handler function.

You could also use framework such as - https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to have a look at the [AWS reference documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html).
The following steps could be done:

1. `~/my-function$ npm install`
2. `~/my-function$ zip -r function.zip .`
3. `~/my-function$ aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my-function --zip-file fileb://function.zip`

Look for node environments available on the [following page from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model.html).
Be aware of the limitations applicable, as Dec 27 2019 , if the deployment package is larger than 50 MB, you must use Amazon S3.